# A faster way to calculate items of a List (Visual Basic .NET)

Tags: vb.net, list

I'm filling up a List (Of Double) by calculating it's items. What i want to do is to find the Indexes of all max-values in a sine-graph.

```
Public Sub Leakage_Current_Result_Verification(list_current As List(Of Double), list_voltage As List(Of Double))
Dim list_values_current As New List(Of Double) 'contains all values from the current-channel
Dim list_values_voltage As New List(Of Double) 'contains all values from the voltage-channel
Dim list_values_current_results As New List(Of Double) 'contains all current-values to the corresponding peak-values from the voltage-channel
Dim list_values_voltage_results As New List(Of Double) 'contains all peak-values from the voltage-channel
Dim list_values_voltage_results_indexes As New List(Of Integer) 'contains all indexes of the peak-vales from the voltage-channel
Dim list_values_current_fault_values As New List(Of Double) 'contains all current values that are bigger than 1mA
Dim list_faultindexes As New List(Of Integer) 'contains all indexes of the current-fault-values
Dim sample_rate As Double = 1000
Dim Range As Integer = 0
Dim PeriodTime As Double

        list_values_current = list_current
        list_values_voltage = list_voltage
    
        PeriodTime = (1 / AmetekNew.Output_Frequency)
        Range = Convert.ToInt32((PeriodTime * sample_rate))
    
        For k = 0 To (list_values_voltage.Count / Range) - 1
    
            list_values_voltage_results.Add(list_values_voltage.GetRange(list_values_voltage.IndexOf(list_values_voltage.Item((k * Range))), k * Range + Range).Max)
            list_values_voltage_results.Add(list_values_voltage.GetRange(list_values_voltage.IndexOf(list_values_voltage.Item((k * Range))), k * Range + Range).Min)
    
        Next
```

I tried to find the maximum-values in a sine-graph and store them into a new List (Of Double). This code takes an extremely long time.
Are there faster methods to perform an action like this?
Can someone give me tips where to research on these methods or instantly knows an answer to my problem.

thanks in advance

Comment: Not seeing much there that I would expect being overly slow.  How big of a data set are dealing with?  What sort of profiling have you done?

Comment: Do you want to find local maxima/minima or an overall maximum/minimum value? And if the former, how are the local extrema defined?

Comment: Are you sure everything should be a list?  As soon as you start doing lookups, you should consider trying to process into a `Dictionary` so that you can move from a linear process to a constant-time process. *Especially* things named "Indexes" make me suspicious that they should be dictionaries instead of lists.

Answer (score 0):

The `List.Max()` and `List.Min()` functions check every element of the list (in this case `range` number of elememts; or even more since `IndexOf()` finds the index of the first element with a given value).  The `List.IndexOf()` function also has to check every element of the list (in this case `list_values_voltage.Count`) upto the first element with the target value.
Every time the functions are called they recalculate their result.

This makes that you code is doing approximately `list_values_voltage.Count * list_values_voltage.Count` commpares of doubles (ak.a. in big O notation 'O(n * n)'.

You can avoid some computations (and possibly get your algirithm more correctly doing what you intend) by changing the `list_values_voltage.IndexOf(list_values_voltage.Item((k *range)))` within both `GetRange(...)` to `(k * range)`.  `(k * range)` is itself an index. It would change the behavior of `list_values_voltage.GetRange()` to always yield `range` number of elements, a single period of your sinus; instead of a longer sequence starting possibly somewhere before `(k * range)` at the first element having the same value as `list_values_voltage.Item(k * range)`.  Would that be acceptable to you?
It would remove ((k * range) -1) element comparisons within either `IndexOf()` or `Max()`/`Min()` from your inner loop.  Making the total number of comparisons `2 * list_values_voltage.Count` ('O(n)').

Note: you're now adding the maximum values not the indexes of these values for that you could use `IndexOf()`, but at a different place than in your code. Its computation cost would be `2 * list_values_voltage.Count * range`. There is a possibilty to calculate these indexes in 'O(n)'.
*(I have to leave that as an exercise you or an other answerer since my battery is dying.)*